# Determine which requests are causing the "Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page" error

Tags: angularjs, protractor

As per various answers and available documentation, Protractor throws this error if the page has pending promises ($timeout or $http requests).
My page does not have any timeouts, and the $http requests taper off quickly when I launch the app manually.
How can I find out the exact promise which is causing this error?

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code in order to help you out.

Comment: This is a frequently observed problem, I'm hoping there's some generic approach to finding out the cause of the problem, instead of using browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;